# Azure webapp bot deployed to Application Service Environment

Tags: botframework

Did anyone deploy Azue Web App Bot using Application Service Environment?
are there any key considerations to be noted? I know we have ASE ILB and ASE External;
Is it possible to host multiple azure webapp bots in one ASE; my question is primarily due to the default lockdown of internet traffice in ASE ILB model and what type of firewall exceptions we will need to ensure
functinally the communication to Azure Bot Service/ Directline happen smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is possible to host multiple azure web app bots in one ASE.** However, care should be taken on **how to have the bot dynamically looks up the pipe name as there a multiple bots inside the same ASE**. Also, the normal DirectLine or other channels **would require a lot of whitelisting to allow traffic into the ILB**, and bot services IPs can change so it would be difficult to maintain long term.

**'Test in WebChat' is not expected to work within an ILB ASE**. It calls out to the DirectLine channel and causes the channel to send a call to the bot's messaging endpoint. In most ASE or VNET scenarios that call will be blocked, but since we don't have static IP addresses so the customer can't whitelist the incoming calls, either. Other than that, Directline channel and Direct Line App Service Extension(DL ASE) should typically work as expected from within an ILB ASE setup. If you are implementing additional features such as OAuth or SSO, then you will need to add a rule to enable [service tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview) for AzureAD.

For more info on DL ASE, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that it helps others with similar queries? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much; that helps; I understand..Its a long way ahead to get this work.. sorry for the delay in accepting the answer.